# how to make a div that change the background of the whole screen

Tags: html, css

i tried this but it only works when the screen is before the vertical scroller appears, and then when you scroll down the background color is back to white.

```css
.background {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: Try `position: fixed;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by default `body` has padding.

"Manjuboyz" solution works to an extent but a globally applied style might cause issues in the future.

This snippet will fix it by removing the default body padding:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body{
            padding:0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .background {
          min-height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          z-index: -9999;
          background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If your page is too long however, you will need the `position: fixed` property, this makes sure that the div will follow the rendered view area on their device by 'fixing' it to the visible view-able screen. [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) has some good examples of it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body{
            padding:0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .background {
          min-height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          z-index: -9999;
          background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the position fixed did the job